# Translate text in select with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i want to translate the text in select option with vuejs how can i do?

```
data: () => {
        
          hiring_types: [
           { value:'contract', text: 'contract'},
            {value:'vat', text: 'vat'}
          ],
    }
```

template:

```
          <b-form-select
              v-model="form.contract_data.hiring_type"
              :options="hiring_types"
              @input="setSelected"
              id="hiring_types"
              :state="validate(form.contract_data.hiring_type)">
           </b-form-select>
```

Comment: check npm package vue-i18n

Comment: i already have I-18n

Answer (score 0):

Just use a computed.

Assuming `'contract'` and `'vat'` are existing translation keys:

```js
computed: {
  translatedOptions() {
    return this.hiring_types.map(i => ({ ...i, text: this.$t(i.text)}))
  }
}
```